# delete query using execute Immediate

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex-5

I want convert varchar2 into date but its occur error give me solution

```
DECLARE
  ADATE VARCHAR2(100):='02/20/1981';
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM emp WHERE HIREDATE= '||to_char(to_date(ADATE,'mm/dd/yy'),'mm/dd/yy');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DELETE');
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use this one:

```
DECLARE
   ADATE   VARCHAR2 (100) := '02/20/1981';
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
         'DELETE FROM emp WHERE HIREDATE= :aDate' using TO_DATE(ADATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy');

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('DELETE');
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. Make sure to use `USING` clause to pass the bind variable to avoid `SQL` injection. Also as mentioned by @Kaushik, there is no need to do `TO_CHAR`.

```
DECLARE
   ADATE   VARCHAR2 (100) := '02/20/1981';
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
         'DELETE FROM emp WHERE HIREDATE= TO_DATE(:ADATE, ''mm/dd/yyyy'')' using adate;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('DELETE');
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert it to `TO_CHAR`. The quotes have to be right and use proper date formats.

```
DECLARE
  ADATE VARCHAR2(100):='02/20/1981';
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM emp WHERE HIREDATE=to_date('''||ADATE||''',''mm/dd/yyyy'')';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DELETE');
END;
```

For your delete operation, you don't even need an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. A block like this should be sufficient.

```
DECLARE
  ADATE VARCHAR2(100):='02/20/1981';
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM emp WHERE HIREDATE=to_date(ADATE,'mm/dd/yyyy');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DELETE');
END;
```